# Fetch url parameters in twig

Tags: twig, opencart-3

this is my URL:

```
192.168.0.101/user1/opc_autopart/upload/index.php?route=product/category&path=20
```

I want to fetch path parameter and below is my code

```
{{ app.request.get('path') }}
```

This code is not working

Answer (score 0):

You may use:

```
{{ app.request.query.get('path') }}
```

to get the `path` query string in twig.

You would better define a default value, in case there is no `path` parameter:

```
{{ app.request.query.get('path')|default('1') }}
```